# Why is my window changes size upon image loading?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an app that changes window size for no obvious reason. It only has a button and a 400x300px image. When the button is pressed, a black image (400x300px) is created and loaded to Image control, which causes the window to increase up to 1800x1400px. It seems like a weird bug to me. Any idea why is this happening?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowSizeTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="Press me" Click="Button_Click"/>

        <Image x:Name="_img" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="400" MinHeight="300"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WindowSizeTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _img.Source = BitmapSource.Create(
                400,
                300,
                96.0,
                96.0,
                PixelFormats.Gray8,
                null,
                new byte[400 * 300],
                400);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` ? What's the image's actual size? Are you sure the same unit is used in the `Image` component and `BitmapSource.Create`?

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke` is useless here, and a possible source of deadlocks. It's used to run code on the UI thread. That event though is already running on the UI thread. At best, that `Invoke` will only add overhead

Answer (score 1):

Set the Image's `Stretch` property to `None` to make sure the Image element uses the exact size of its `Source` bitmap.

```
<Image x:Name="_img" MinWidth="400" MinHeight="300" Stretch="None"/>
```

Comment: But I actually need image to stretch. I don't need window (or image?) to change size abruptly.

Comment: Then set the Image's Width and Height explicitly.

Comment: Can you please explain me how loading 400x300px image makes image control 1800x1400px? The fun thing is if i resize window (even a little bit) before pressing button, the app behaves just as i expect it to behave: loading image doesn't change window size, image stretches when i resize window manually.

Answer (score -2):

Handle your window "Loaded" event to resolve this issue:

```
void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's funny. Then why don't you simply remove the `<Window  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ... />` from your XAML in the first place? You are overriding it immediately. The solution is to modify the XAML attribute assignment to `<Window SizeToContent="Manual" ... />` . Please delete this post.